# HTML video appearing only in Firefox, not in any other browser when served from a local server

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, opera

I have a simple page with a `<video>` element and I am testing it with a simple server I run with python (`python -m http.server`). I've also tried with JavaScript `http-server` and I'm getting the same results.

I've been testing mostly in Firefox for now, but it used to work in Chrome and Opera. However, today I tried to open the page and it's only working in Firefox. The video doesn't appear in Chrome, Opera and Edge. When I go to the console, I get the following issues:

**Chrome:**

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

**Opera:**

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Invalid color name.

Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'h' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at chrome-extension://hhckidpbkbmoeejbddojbdgidalionif/components/video_toolbar.js:310:46

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)
```

**Edge:**

Doesn't even show issues.

If I open the html file directly, without the server, the video appears in all browsers, but I'm also displaying .vtt captions, so I need to test with the server.

What I have is a very simple `<video>` element:

```html
<div class="video">
  <video id="vid" controls>
    <source src="some_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="subtitles" src="some_captions.vtt" srclang="en" default>
  </video>
</div>
```

I've read that I should disable extensions, but I really haven't installed any in these browsers. I've also read that I should disable JavaScript and CSS source maps, but that didn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

Tried it here, with the video in the same folder as my test.html.
mp4 video is working on firefox, chrome and edge.
maybe some problem with your webserver?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)
```

irritates me - hit F12, switch to network and see from where it tries to open your video (maybe you need to click play first). Right click it  - open in new tab to check the url and if the video is working

Comment: Did this quick test in Firefox and Opera. Both say they're getting the video from `http://localhost:8000/some_video.mp4`. Opened that URL in a new tab of both browsers and both are showing and playing it. I've been thinking about what could've changed in my computer that made this stop working, and the only thing I can think of is that McAfee was disabled and only Windows Defender is working for now. I had to give firewall permissions to the server apps; but they have those permissions. Can you think of anything else that could be affecting this?

Comment: Another interesting thing I just found. Got rid of the `<track>` element and now the video shows in Opera and Chrome. I'm still getting the same issues I posted, but the video is there. What could be happening here with the captions?

Comment: can you just put the code within a plain html file and run it from your pc, without the http Server? So you can see if it's a problem with your server or your browsers. As mentioned above it's no problem of your html code, because that works fine here on my pc.

Comment: I had tested the html directly in the browser without server and it worked, but I thought it was a problem with the browsers and those requests because of those issues I saw in the console. I've been trying to make it work and just found a way, which is not using the `default` attribute for the `<track>` element. Now I only have to find out why that attribute caused that. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio to test the code in localhost and I got the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)` at first. The video shows but the subtitles doesn't show and the `.vtt` file can't be found.

Then I found the cause of the issue: `.vtt` file MIME type is not added. Then I add the MIME type in **Web.config** like below and the video and subtitles work well in all browsers:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".vtt" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vtt" mimeType="text/vtt" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The issue in your situation is also `Failed to load` some file and related with the subtitles `<track>` element, so I suspect if it is also caused by file MIME type not being added. You can check which file is failed to load in your site and adding corresponding MIME type to see if it can fix the issue.

Comment: The thing is that my problem is actually that what doesn't appear is the video. I "temporarily" fixed the issue by not using the `default` attribute on the `<track>` element and then setting the `mode` property to `showing` with JavaScript. I can try what you suggest, but I'd have to find out how to add time MIME type to the python http server or the JavaScript http server.

Comment: Have you tried with other videos? The video should show. I use your code and download the video and subtitle from [this demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track), it works well.